# How can I set boundaries on the screen?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make it so that If the arrow reaches the screen boundary it will go up and turn around continuing the code so that I can create a piece of art. I've been looking for a post to answer my problem but I can't find anything that's specific to this problem.

```
import random
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

dots = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
dots.speed("fastest")
dots.penup()
dots.goto(-350, -350)

# setting x and y-axis:
dots.xcor()
dots.ycor()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 800
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

color_list = [(250, 246, 243), (211, 154, 98), (53, 107, 131), (235, 240, 244), (177, 78, 33),
              (198, 142, 35), (116, 155, 171), (124, 79, 98), (123, 175, 157), (226, 197, 130), (190, 88, 109),
              (12, 50, 64),
              (56, 39, 19), (41, 168, 128), (50, 126, 121), (199, 123, 143), (166, 21, 30), (224, 93, 79)]

random_color = random.choice(color_list)

for _ in range(100):
    new_random_color = random.choice(color_list)
    dots.dot(20, new_random_color)
    dots.fd(40)

x, y = dots.position

if x < WIDTH:
    if y < HEIGHT:
        dots.undo()  # undo error
        dots.left(180)  # turn around
        dots.forward(10)  # redo movement but in new direction

screen.exitonclick()
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run your code? How does that differ from what you want? Have you tried any debugging? [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great techniques to get you started.

Comment: I don't get an error however as the for loop does it just continues to put circles when I want it to turn around when It hits the boundary and then go up too

Comment: Thus eventually giving me a "Hirst Spot Painting" kind of design

Comment: I ran your program. It draws a bunch of circles across the bottom and then throws an error. I don't think the error is what you are asking about, though, so let's ignore that for now. After it draws the circles across the bottom from left to right, what should it do? When you say "turn around", I imagine it going from right to left instead. Is that what you mean? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Already been answered. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what's missing is just to relocate pointer to starting X axis with  Y axis + your interval. Easier way would be to follow similar logic. Allocate your pointer in the beginning with setheading() method then indicate what path to follow.

or

you need to indicate one more goto() method like

new_y = dots.ycor + (interval what you want eg: 50)
dots.goto(-350, new_y) and create for loop depending how many rows you need. Personally I've done this as follows:

```
dots = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
dots.speed("fastest")
dots.penup()
dots.setheading(225)
dots.forward(300)
dots.setheading(0)

random_color = random.choice(color_list)
num_of_dots = 100

for dot_count in range(1, num_of_dots + 1):
    dots.penup()
    dots.dot(20, random.choice(color_list))
    dots.forward(50)

    if dot_count % 10 == 0:
        dots.setheading(90)
        dots.forward(50)
        dots.setheading(180)
        dots.forward(500)
        dots.setheading(0)
```

Comment: That's worked I just had to make a few tiny tweaks but thank you so much!